# What is the template hierarchy name in Wordpress for the next page of a gallery

Tags: wordpress, templates, gallery, hierarchy, custom-post-type

I have a gallery page in Wordpress **page-gallery.php** which is a custom post type displays 50 pictures but 10 on each page and you have to click the next page on the bottom like **( prev 1 2 3 4 next )**

1. what would be the page name for where that next page would take me from page-gallery.php?
2. Would it be page-gallery-2.php and so forth just naming it -3 -4 -5?
3. if so would Wordpress already know thats the next page or would you need to manually link those pages?
4. Does **the_permalink()** play a part in this?

Can someone people clarify. Thank you!

Comment: The pages you're referring to are called paged pages. They use the same template as page 1.

Comment: Im sorry I don't fully understand, because I would be running a custom loop for the gallery post type to show all of the gallery images in the post type. So how would splitting the posts with paged pages work?

Comment: Posting the code for your page-gallery.php would help us determine what's missing. WP has helper functions to build pagination elements, check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: It's nothing special just the gallery being displayed from the custom post type with WP_Query `<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'gallery'  
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_field( 'image' ); ?> <br/>
<p><?php the_field( 'name' ); ?></p>
</li>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>There are no posts or pages here</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>`

Comment: Hey im sorry but it's not letting me format my code correctly. I put my code within back tics but every time I hit enter it sends the reply instead of giving it a line break